# Limiting Application permission scopes to specific Site Collection(s)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I need an Access Token to make calls into a SharePoint site using Application scopes (Client Credentials).

Is there a way to limit the scope of application permissions? I am currently unable to receive Admin Concent for my application as this would allow access to every SharePoint Site in their Tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we grant the application `Sites.Manage.All` permission, we will be able to manage all the sites. We can not limit the application scope to specific Site Collection(s).

The application permissions are for all the site collections.

[image]